# Comparing two lists using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

If I have 2 lists of strings:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>("010", "111", "123");
List<string> secondList = new List<string>("010", "111", "999");
```

How can I compare each individual character in each item from the lists? Ex: Should compare "0" with "0", "1" with "1", "0" with "0" and so on. It appears that I can use `SelectMany` but I am stuck on how to do it

EDIT:

These lists should return true when compared with each other (as asterisk means any character and I am validating to ensure that each item is exactly 3 chars in length)

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>("010", "111", "123");
List<string> secondList = new List<string>("010", "1*1", "***");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to compare for a matching character sequence between your lists:

```
bool sameCharacters = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(firstList.SelectMany(x => x), 
                                               secondList.SelectMany(x => x));
```

This would result in `true`, i.e. for the following two lists - their character sequences match (`"010111123"` for both), their individual string entries do not:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string> {"010", "111", "123" };
List<string> secondList = new List<string> {"010", "11", "1123" };
```

**Edit in response to comments:**

For a wildcard match you could use `Zip()` and compare each character, return true if they match based on wildcard conditions, then just check that each element in the zipped sequence is `true`.

<s>var isWildCardMatch = firstList.SelectMany(x => x).Zip(secondList.SelectMany( x => x), 
                                              (a,b) =>
        {
            if(a==b || a =='*' || b == '*')
                return true;
            return false;</s>

```
    }).All( x=> x);
```

Above approach crossed string entry boundaries, which would cause false matches - here a better approach:

```
bool isWildCardMatch = firstList.Zip(secondList, (x, y) =>
{
    var matchWord = y.Select((c, i) => c == '*' ? x[i] : c);
    return matchWord.SequenceEqual(x);
}).All(x => x);
```

Comment: Hhm, just curious. Why would you want to make a character-based sequence-equals when sequence-equals over strings also compares the characters in the strings (as in my answer)?

Comment: @lasseespeholt - I have special logic to add and I need to do that on a character by character comparison.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Because your solution will return false in the example I give - a "character stream" based solution returns false. It appeared that this is what OP wanted, but of course I might be wrong.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - If a character has an asterisk, then it should match any character. Given that, should I be breaking down the `firstList.SelectMany` and `secondList.SelectMany` and looping through them?

Comment: @BrokenGlass Ahh okay ;) I interpret the question in another way. I guess OP have to explain how the semantics should work then.

Comment: @DotnetDude: Updated my answer with a wildcard match solution

Comment: Thanks! Whats the intent of using the `All`

Comment: This doesn't check whether or not strings are of equal length. Didn't you want that, DotnetDude?

Comment: @DotNetDude: The zipped sequence contains a bunch of booleans, true for a match, false otherwise - `All()` returns true if they are all matches, false otherwise.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: The last version does check, since `SequenceEqual()` on words of different lengths returns false.

Comment: Didn't see that ;) No problems then :)

Answer (score 5):

**Updated with wildcards**

```
class WildcardStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1.Length != s2.Length) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (s1[i] != s2[i] && s1[i] != '*' && s2[i] != '*')
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "999"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "999"};

bool res = firstList.SequenceEqual(secondList, new WildcardStringComparer()); // True
```

and

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "999"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "*99"};

bool res = firstList.SequenceEqual(secondList, new WildcardStringComparer()); // True
```

and

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "999"};
List<string> secondList = new List<string>{"010", "111", "199"};

bool res = firstList.SequenceEqual(secondList, new WildcardStringComparer()); // False
```

Comment: I'd like to compare character by character and not item by item as I have special logic I need to apply

Comment: @DotnetDude Okay :) Maybe you should explain in a little more detail what you want. That way you might get better answers.

Comment: +1: Using a custom comparer looks like the way to go in this case, looks clean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare the first character of the first string in the first list to the first character of the first string of the second list, the second character of the first string in the first list to the second character of the first string in the second list, etc.  I can think of two implementations.

The one I would start with:

```
var firstCharList = new List<char>();
var secondCharList = new List<char>();

firstList.foreach(s => 
 {
   foreach(char c in s)
   {
      firstCharList.Add(c);
   }
  });

secondList.foreach(s =>
{
   foreach(char c in s)
   {
      secondCharList.Add(c);
   }
});

for(int i = 0; i < firstCharList.Length; i++)
{
   if(firstCharList[i] == secondCharList[i]) yield return i;
}
```

That would generate a list (or array, or whatever) of ints that correspond to indexes of which both strings had the same character.

The second would be something like:

```
firstList.foreach(s =>
{
   var index = firstList.IndexOf(s);
   var sPrime = secondList[index];
   for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
   {
      if(s[i] == sPrime[i]) yield return s[i];
   }
}
```

That one just returns any characters that are equal at the same indexes.